# Sticky position not working on div element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a div sticky positioned relative to the viewport so it sticks to the top when it gets scrolled out of view but it isn't working.

```css
#navigation {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #AA1111;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
}

header {
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="page">
    <header>
      <div id="navigation">
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Alternatives? @VXp

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sticky will stick to the top while the parent element is still visible. With that said, your parent element (header) only contains the sticky element, thus will scroll out of view as the navigation would normally. If you had another element inside of the header that had some height, the navigation would stick to the top until that scrolls out of view too.

https://jsfiddle.net/1zbnr2ho/

Like others have said, sticky doesn't have great browser support, and maybe what you're looking for could just be accomplished with position: fixed?

```css
#navigation {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #AA1111;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
}


body {
  min-height: 5000px;
}

.other {
  height: 500px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <header>
    <div id="navigation"></div>
    <div class="other">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</div>
  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: Upvoting because I was about to post the same solution, but you could mention that `position:sticky` should come after `position:-webkit-sticky` (or, any unprefixed property should always come last, after the prefixed values).

Comment: Unfortunately I need the effect that 'sticky' offers because I don't want it to always stick to the top of the viewport. I'll probably just use JavaScript to detect when it's scrolled out of view and apply fixed positioning to it. Thanks!

Comment: @MrLister makes a good point, you should have your vendor prefixed version first, and your real version second. This can make a difference.